# "MaximumRecievedMessageSize" exceed - Better way of handling this?

Tags: database, wcf

The data I'm trying to send out through a WCF service is a Northwind Database table (suppliers) which holds about 29 records, and is already exceeding the maximum length of a message I can send. I've looked around for answers and everyone says the same thing: Increase the "maxRecievedMessageSize" in the .config file.

However, this seems very wrong to me - it feels too much like a work around rather than solving the issue (Ex: What if it exceeds the maximum amount I can set it too?). Instead, is there a way to break up the message into chunks? The service itself is modeled by WSSF, so I'm having hard time finding "where" the message is being serialized in the first place (I do not provide code since WSSF provides a very strict template to work on, as I'm aware).

Side-Note/Question: I have a "backup" plan where I can execute a stored command onto the database that only brings back 10 rows of data (at a specified starting point when calling the function). However, I would have to call the function that does this several times. Would this still be better than breaking the message into chunks?

I apologize for not displaying any code but I feel as though it will only cause more confusion. If it is necessary, then I will try and clear this question up to the best of my ability asap. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: For query type operations returning lots of rows, I provide Skip/Take properties on my request objects so the client can control paging. Would this be workable?

Comment: Hmmm, I did not think of that! I have used that before, just never came to mind. I had simply just limited the results in my LINQ statements but Skip/take looks a tad cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Provide `Skip` and `Take` properties on your request object to allow the client to control paging.